# maven throwing error when adding casbah to it

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, mongodb, casbah, mongodb-scala

I have added casbah to my dependancies using

```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.mongodb.casbah</groupId>
  <artifactId>casbah_2.8.0</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Then i just wrote a simple mongo connection statement

```
 val mongoConn = MongoConnection()
 val mongoDB = mongoConn("test")
 val newObj = MongoDBObject("foo" -> "bar","x"->"y","pie"->3.14,"spam"->"eggs")
```

Then i compiled it

```
mvn compile
```

But it is throwing errors that it cannot find the goal

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test-project: Could not resolve depend
encies for project org.scala-lang:test-project:jar:default: Could not find artif
act com.mongodb.casbah:casbah_2.8.0:jar:2.1.5.0 in scala-tools.org (http://scala
-tools.org/repo-releases) -> [Help 1]
```

Can some one tell me what the problem is. I didnt make any other changes to the POM other than adding this dependancy. Truth is i dont know what else to change in it. But i also observed that intellij idea shows auto complete options for casbah objects and classes, all this is so confusing for me.

Comment: Looks like a Maven problem to me. The equivalent dependency (`libraryDependencies += "com.mongodb.casbah" % "casbah_2.8.0" % "2.1.5.0"`) works fine in sbt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying the below(note the type), replace scala.version with 2.8.0 or which version you are using.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mongodb.casbah</groupId>
      <artifactId>casbah_${scala.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.5-1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and resolved it with splitting whole `casbah` dependency into list of subdependencies:

```
<properties>
    <scala.version>2.9.0-1</scala.version>
</properties>
<!--Database : casbah -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mongodb.casbah</groupId>
   <artifactId>casbah-commons_${scala.version}</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.5-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.mongodb.casbah</groupId>
   <artifactId>casbah-query_${scala.version}</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.5-1</version>
   </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mongodb.casbah</groupId>
   <artifactId>casbah-gridfs_${scala.version}</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.5-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mongodb.casbah</groupId>
   <artifactId>casbah-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.5-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Don't forget to change `scala` and `casbah` versions to respectively `2.8.0` and `2.1.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is an incorrect dependency to specify.

If we look at the [repository](http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/com/mongodb/casbah/casbah_2.8.0/2.1.5.0/), we see only the pom file for this dependency and no jar.  Maybe, you should try specifying [casba-core](http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/com/mongodb/casbah/casbah-core_2.9.0-1/) or something similar.